# Unknown type name in C linked list structure

Tags: c, gcc, data-structures, compiler-errors, linked-list

I got a structure like this in a header file :

```
typedef struct {
    LIGNE *precedent;
    PERSONNE individu;
    LIGNE *suivant;
} LIGNE;
```

But when I compile, I got this error :

```
error: unknown type name ‘LIGNE’
  LIGNE *precedent;
  ^~~~~
error: unknown type name ‘LIGNE’
  LIGNE *suivant;
```

I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `LIGNE` is not known until the structure is completed. You must provide a struct tag and use that inside the struct: `typedef struct LIGNE{... struct LIGNE *suivant;} LIGNE;` The tag name can be same as type name or a different one. Note: `LIGNE` is not the same as `struct LIGNE`!

Comment: @Gerhardh It works, thanks. I tried `typedef struct LIGNE` and `struct LIGNE *suivant` but not both at the same time haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the commants and in the [Tomo Ceferin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12917919/tomo-ceferin)'s answer, your compiler has no idea of what `LIGNE` is until line 5.

One solution would be to typedef your structure before its declaration:

```
typedef struct S_LIGNE LIGNE;

struct S_LIGNE {
    LIGNE *precedent;
    PERSONNE individu;
    LIGNE *suivant;
};
```

This way, your compiler knoww that `LIGNE` is a typedef for `struct S_LIGNE`.

Answer (score 0):

Put yourself in compilers shoes:

```c
1: typedef struct {
2:     LIGNE *precedent;
3:     PERSONNE individu;
4:     LIGNE *suivant;
5: } LIGNE;
```

In line 2 you say that you want a pointer to something of type `LIGNE`. That's a problem for compiler since it has no idea what `LIGNE` is until line 5. Granted, this is compiler being a little dumb. A pointer to anything is the same size, so as far as layout of structure goes, it shouldn't matter. However, C compiler wants to know what sort of pointer this.
As @Gerhardh suggested, you can trick it by prefixing lines 2 and 4 with `struct`. Compiler sees this and reads it as *pointer to structure*, suddenly no longer caring that it knows not anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
typedef struct {
    struct LIGNE *precedent;
    PERSONNE individu;
    struct LIGNE *suivant;
} LIGNE;
```